# Simultaneous builds with different parameters with msbuild

Tags: msbuild, windows-installer

I am not a Windows developer. :)  I've tried looking around the project source and Microsoft's msbuild documentation and don't seen an immediately obvious solution to this.

Is there a way I can produce multiple windows installers from the same source directory but using different properties simultaneously?

---

Background:

There is a project that I have to build from time to time in Windows using the following command: `"c:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" /property:id=1234 /t:rebuild update.sln`

It generates an MSI file named `update_1234.msi`

Inside that installer, the 'id' property creates a registry key with the value.  It's pretty straight forward and an extremely simple MSI file.

Sometimes I get one request per day to create an installer.  Sometimes I get 30 requests from my boss per day.  I would like to automate it with a simple internal web page.

I created a simple page that asks for the ID number and has a submit button.  It works for generating an MSI file--but during further testing I noticed that simultaneous builds will 'trample' each other.  i.e. if two builds are fired off within rapid succession and they overlap, the installer is generated for one and only one of the builds.  The rest die with errors about files being in use by other processes.

I figured the error could be because of a complete rebuild, so I tried `/t:build`.  While there are no errors during simultaneous builds, it also doesn't produce an MSI file.

Each rebuild takes ~7 seconds, and each build takes 0.5 seconds.

I suppose one solution would be to create several copies of the project into something like `c:\build1` and `c:\build2` and so on...and distribute the builds between those folders, but that seems like a hack.

Can msbuild generate multiple MSI files from the same source at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

This solution still feels a bit hacky, but it accomplished my goal:

`"c:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" /property:id=1234 /t:rebuild /p:OutputPath=c:\build\1234 /p:DefineConstants=id=1234 update.wixproj`

I basically just directly build the WixProject and specify a unique output directory (c:\build\nnnn) for each build.  I can set a scheduled job to run daily to use `forfiles` to delete old directories.